# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using a `ViewPager` with two fragments. When the app is opened the first fragment is set as the default. If the first fragment is not swiped to the next fragment and then the app is closed it crashes. I have tried using `onViewCreated` as answered in other questions on StackOverflow but still it doesn't seem to work.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        //getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_RECIPIENT_IDS, ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
        query.orderByDescending(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
//              getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                if (e == null) {
                    // We found messages!
                    mMessages = messages;

                    String[] usernames = new String[mMessages.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (ParseObject message : mMessages) {
                        usernames[i] = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                        MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(
                                getListView().getContext(),
                                mMessages);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        // refill the adapter!
                        ((MessageAdapter)getListView().getAdapter()).refill(mMessages);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
     at io.wyntr.peepster.Fragments.InboxFragment$1.done(InboxFragment.java:73)
     at io.wyntr.peepster.Fragments.InboxFragment$1.done(InboxFragment.java:58)
     at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:116)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: What if you remove `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`?

Comment: Or you might want to add `super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried adding but it still crashes